# Can a JWT be safely inlined in an html response?

Tags: javascript, html, oauth, jwt, single-page-application

What are the repercussions of inlining a JWT or other user info in a script tag in an html response.

I'd like to supply my users with unique JWTs to make authenticated API requests.  My application is architected as a SPA so these tokens wouldn't be created all the time (only on page refresh & load) and probably aren't a hugely expensive cost anyways.

Is this a common design pattern for passing credentials to the front end for ajax calls?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just save the jwt in localstorage?

Comment: @Jalil localstorage is only available to the client, so this still requires a means of sending the jwt to the client.  I'd prefer not to block my app from loading while a token is fetched via ajax upon page load.